# igraph + R vertices coloured by condition (preferably continuous colours)

Tags: r, igraph

New to igraph. I would like to have vertex colours be defined by another parameter, preferably continuous colours (think heatmap or grayscale).

```
clusters_only <- as.character(temp_df$SeqID)
v_names <- data.frame(c(unique_order, as.character(temp_df$SeqID)))
graph_order <- graph.data.frame(temp_df, directed = FALSE, vertices = v_names)
V(graph_order)[clusters_only]$size <- ? #continuous colour based on variable in temp_df
```

Any ideas?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `color` attribute of vertices to specify the vertex colors. It may be a string (containing a color name known to R) or a numeric value, in which case the color will be selected from the current palette. E.g.:

```
library(igraph)
g <- grg.game(100, 0.2)
V(g)$color <- 1:100
palette(gray.colors(100))
plot(g)
```

Alternatively, you may specify the colors as the argument of `plot` instead of assigning them to a vertex attribute:

```
plot(g, vertex.color <- 1:100)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had better luck with this syntax:

```
R> library(igraph)
R> g <- grg.game(100, 0.2)
R> V(g)$color <- 1:100
R> g$palette <- grey.colors(100)    ####  updated this line
R> plot(g)
```

Maybe the grammar has changed since the original answer?